# OR a list of booleans with Groovy in one line?

Tags: collections, groovy

I have a method in a groovy class that returns a list of booleans, but what I really want is the result with the values in this list `OR`'d together (see example below)

**Example output:**

```
def result1 = foo*.isDisplayed() // [false, false, false] (I want false)
def reslut2 = bar*.isDisplayed() // [true, true, true] (I want true)
def result3 = baz*.isDisplayed() // [true, false, false] (I want true)
```

I'm sure there is an appropraite [Groovy collection method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html) but I'm failing to find the right one.

Clearly, I could just loop over everything with a `for` loop ( `for(boolean val : result)...`) but I *know* there's a sexy one-liner.

I found a way (using [`.findResult`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findResult%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)! Not quite a *beautiful* 1-liner, but good enough. I'll leave this question up for a bit, and if no answer, I'll self-answer with this.

```
def result = (foobar*.isDisplayed().findResult { it == true ?: null } != null)
```

I still think there is a more elegant way...

Comment: You can change the subject of question to `OR` or change the question to "I want false" in the third case. Glad that was helpful. :)

Comment: Another [simpler approach would be like this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6664030/). Mainly `(result1, result2, result3) = [foo, bar, baz].collectNested{it.isDisplayed()}*.any()`

Comment: @dmahapatro nice, thanks. Not actually how my code looks/works, but a good tool for the bag! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`any()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#any%28%29) if you want true in case of `result3` (which actually is OR instead of AND).

```
def result1 = foo*.isDisplayed().any() // [false, false, false] (I want false)
def reslut2 = bar*.isDisplayed().any() // [true, true, true] (I want true)
def result3 = baz*.isDisplayed().any() // [true, false, false] (I want true)
```

On the contrary, if you need false for `result3` (AND condition) then use [`every()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#every%28%29)

```
def result3 = baz*.isDisplayed().every() //AND gives false.
```

A [simpler approach to the above code.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6664030/)

Mainly:

```
def result1, result2, result3
(result1, result2, result3) = [foo, bar, baz]
                                 .collectNested{it.isDisplayed()}*.any()
```

Comment: wow, much better than the solution I just found and editted in lol. Well done!

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for the link. I edited the link to refer Object in Groovy instead of `DefaultGroovyMethods`.

Comment: hahah, crap, and I said `AND` when I meant `OR`. Thanks for that update